# Unable to start HandlerSocket with mariadb

Tags: centos, mariadb, handlersocket

For some reason, I cannot get HandlerSocket to start listening when I start mariadb (version 
10.0.14).  I am using Cent OS 6.5.

my.cnf has the following settings:

```
handlersocket_port = 9998
handlersocket_port_wr = 9999
handlersocket_address = 127.0.0.1
```

Calling "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'handlersocket%'" from the mariaDb prompt shows:

```
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                 | Value     |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| handlersocket_accept_balance  | 0         |
| handlersocket_address         | 127.0.0.1 |
| handlersocket_backlog         | 32768     |
| handlersocket_epoll           | 1         |
| handlersocket_plain_secret    |           |
| handlersocket_plain_secret_wr |           |
| handlersocket_port            | 9998      |
| handlersocket_port_wr         | 9999      |
| handlersocket_rcvbuf          | 0         |
| handlersocket_readsize        | 0         |
| handlersocket_sndbuf          | 0         |
| handlersocket_threads         | 16        |
| handlersocket_threads_wr      | 1         |
| handlersocket_timeout         | 300       |
| handlersocket_verbose         | 10        |
| handlersocket_wrlock_timeout  | 12        |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

I can start mariadb successfully, but when I check to see which ports are actively listening,
neither 9998 nor 9999 show up.  I've checked the mysqld.log file, but no errors seem to be occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here - 
SELINUX needed to be set to permissive mode to get HandlerSocket started.